# Exec VLC in GUI from PHP with Network Stream

Tags: php, vlc

I'm trying to execute VLC player with some stream URL but I cant make it work.

```
$test= "\"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" http://tv.tv:89/tv/tv/33222/4449.ts";
shell_exec($test);
```

When I execute it, there is the `vlc.exe` process in Task Manager but no GUI. Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PHP script is running with the same user credentials as you are logged in.
If it's running with different credentials, you won't see a window because a different user "owns" the window.

Comment: It have full rights. Running on local wamp as Administrator user.

Comment: Are you logged in as Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems trying to run ffmpeg from PHP. It seems to run it as a background process, did you need the GUI? If not then the stream should still work. If you wan the GUI though this is what I did in the end was:

1. Created a batch file that ran the stream and whatever else
2. Convert to exe.
3. Create a windows task schedule and target that exe.
4. Then used php to run the task schedule

Mine was for recording to file in new directories. It is a bit of a work around but it works. If you have found a better way, i would love to hear it.

Mitchell